# how can I override ScreenCaptureProcessor path?

Tags: android, screenshot

Hi Iam implementing screenshot taking to espresso tests 
I Did it successfully with this.

```
private void captureScreenshot(String name) {
ScreenCapture capture = Screenshot.capture();
    capture.setFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG);
    capture.setName(name);
    try {
        capture.process();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
```

problem is that I can not change the path where screenshot file is saved 
  it is set in BasicScreenCaptureProcessor class but it's unclear to me  how to get to override the path or create own ScreencaptureProcessor with different path.

here is the android documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/screenshot/BasicScreenCaptureProcessor.html#mDefaultScreenshotPath

Comment: Hi  I ended up implementing this by copying the files from default screencapture folder to the destination I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The variables defining the location of the images and other details can be overridden by extending the `BasicScreenCaptureProcessor` as such:

```
public class CustomScreenCaptureProcessor extends BasicScreenCaptureProcessor {

    public CustomScreenCaptureProcessor() {
        mTag = "CustomScreenCaptureProcessor";
        mFileNameDelimiter = "-";
        mDefaultFilenamePrefix = "screenshot";
        mDefaultScreenshotPath = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
    }
}
```

And finally rather than calling `process()` on `screenCapture`, pass it to `CustomScreenCaptureProcessor` instance to process it instead as such:

```
private CustomScreenCaptureProcessor processor = new CustomScreenCaptureProcessor();

private void captureScreenshot(String name) {
    ScreenCapture capture = Screenshot.capture();
    capture.setFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG);
    capture.setName(name);
    try {
        processor.process(capture);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
}
```